# thread execution should stop when random number being generated in for loop (1-100) equals natural numbers generated (1,2,3...100)

Tags: java, multithreading

main theme of the program is that thread should be stopped when i run two threads ie one thread is generating random numbers and other generating natural numbers the thread execution must be stopped when they both generate same number

class methmatch {
    public void match() {

```
    }

}
```

class Randgen extends Thread {

```
 static int value;
public void run() {
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {

             value = 1 + random.nextInt(100);
             System.out.println(value); 
             try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

}
}
```

}

class Ordergen extends Thread {

```
static int j;
public  void run() {

    for (int i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {

        for ( j = 1; j <= 100; j++)
        {

              System.out.println(j);
              try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
}
```

}

}

public class Randmatch {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Ordergen obj1 = new Ordergen();
    Randgen obj2 = new Randgen();
    methmatch obj3= new methmatch();
    obj1.start();
    obj2.start();

}
```

}

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, please [edit] your question to improve its formatting. Thanks.

Comment: Why would the ordered generation have 2 for loops?  And would you really want your random generator to only try 100 times before giving up?  Should the ordered generator wait for the random thread to match?  Or should it start over at 1?